# xp:links not working on iOS with bootstrap

Tags: iphone, mobile, drop-down-menu, twitter-bootstrap-3, xpages

Using bootstrap with xpages, which is great.

However, I have a menu on the left, which works in the browser, but on iOS, it correctly collapses under a "Menu" button, which when you click, expands the menu structure, however clicking the links in the menu does nothing, only adds # to the URL.

If I use markup like

```
<a href="LINK HERE">Test Link</a>
```

It works correctly, however I need it to be an xp:link as I am setting some sessionScope variables.

Has anyone encountered this problem with a fix? Or know a way to set sessionScope variables in xpages  using href markup?

Here is the code which shows the first link in the nav:

```
<div>

                  <ul class="nav" role="">
                      <li>
                          <label label-default="" class="tree-toggle nav-header">
<i class="fa fa-caret-square-o-down fa-fw"></i>    Obligors...</label>
                          <ul class="nav tree">

                          <li>
                              <xp:link escape="true" id="lnkByCountry"
                        text="by Country">

                        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
                            refreshMode="complete" immediate="true">
                            <xp:this.action>

                                <xp:actionGroup>
                                    <xp:actionGroup>
                                        <xp:executeScript>
                                            <xp:this.script><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.viewToDisplay="masterList"
sessionScope.sortingColumn=""}]]></xp:this.script>
                                        </xp:executeScript>
                                        <xp:openPage
                                            name="/index.xsp">
                                        </xp:openPage>
                                    </xp:actionGroup>

                                </xp:actionGroup>
                            </xp:this.action>
                        </xp:eventHandler>
                    </xp:link>
                              </li>

                          </ul>
```

Comment: There is a known bug in iOS8 before 9.0.1 FP3

Comment: I thought that bug was more or less specific to the dojomobile controls.  I don't think it had any effect on <xp:link> from a bootstrap application.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right David

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, is the problem the links under the "obligors"? or the "obligors" itself? I think you shoud read your question again and try to rephrase it. if you mean you click "obligors" please provide the code for that link. your question also indicat that it is working in IOS. good questions gives good answers

Comment: Hi Thomas,The problem is with the link under obligors....

The wording was perhaps a bit misleading. Basically, the menu works in iOS exactly as it should - Showing the menu button as a drop down, and all dropdowns within the menu work, (Obligors for example is a dropdown) and the links show correctly, however when CLICKING any of the the actual links, which should simply reload the page and set some sessionScope variables does nothing except put # at the end of the URL...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, for ref - I removed all my xp:links and built simple href links, and created a new page for each of my views rather than 1 page with a few view custom controls on it, so each link in the nav opens a new page now rather than refreshing the current one.

Then on each of the page load events, I set the session scope variables.

This means the links in the menu now work on mobile....

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a good answer.  Sometimes stuff like this breaks because an event handler gets attached to the view tag by accident and that messes everything up.  Might want to look for that.  Maybe even create a clean new xpage with a button to see is that works.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion David....

I created a blank page, and put the navigator on it, and it works fine - However, the navigation doesnt appear as a clickable menu dropdown...

When I then create a new xpage, and put my bootstrap layout application custom control on, then place a new basic nav in the left facet, it correctly puts the nav under a menu button dropdown, but the links within it do not work....

I've been reading a few things about clicking in iOS and changing code to handle hover instead etc... could this possibly be the way forward?